# “They shook their heads” or “They shook their head”?

Tags: grammaticality, nouns, grammatical-number

Should one say **they shook their heads** in disbelief or **they shook their head** in disbelief? The first kind of conjures up many-headed people? Similarly should one say they referred the question to **their husbands/husband**?

Comment: Did *they* have one head/husband between them? If so, use the singular.

Comment: If it's a group they shake their heads.  If it's a single individual he shakes his head.

Comment: Similar: [“They're using a cell phone” vs. “They're using cell phones”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/301625/theyre-using-a-cell-phone-vs-theyre-using-cell-phone)

Comment: *Plural* if they were each shaking their own head. *Singular* if they were shaking their leader.

Answer (score 2):

The earliest instance of "shook their heads in disbelief" in a Google Books search covering the years 1700 through 2008 is from 1871. From "[Sparks from the Village Forge](https://books.google.com/books?id=fuARAAAAYAAJ&pg=RA1-PA28&dq=%22shook+their+heads+in+disbelief%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=W-SlVMuCF5fboATdmICoCg&ved=0CCUQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=%22shook%20their%20heads%20in%20disbelief%22&f=false)," in *The Shamrock*, volume 8 (March 1871):

> The magistrates whispered again : and **shook their heads in disbelief**. The old man was wanting to save Mark, they said. The truth was, however, that he was, when the note arose, in that reverie of memory, which laid its spell upon him when his eyes looked over the land and saw only vanished scenes.

The most recent is from 2008 (the last year included in my search). From Karen Linamen, [*Due to Rising Energy Costs, the Light at the End of the Tunnel Has Been Turned Off*](https://books.google.com/books?id=CjbG695DVkYC&q=%22shook+their+heads+in+disbelief%22&dq=%22shook+their+heads+in+disbelief%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=q-KlVOmnC8KyoQSwwoCQDA&ved=0CCgQ6AEwAg) (2008) [combined snippets]:

> But now I'm forty-six. So when my folks came into the kitchen and **shook their heads in disbelief** at all their gyrating offspring, in-laws, and grandkids, well . . . what could they do? Send me to my room? Actually, they may have shaken their heads in disbelief, but they were smiling at the same time.

Altogether, the Google Books search turns up 84 matches for "shook their heads in disbelief" during the search period and 0 matches for "shook their head in disbelief." So in published writing there appears to be a strong preference for the former phrase over the latter. This not to say that "shook their head in disbelief" is wrong, or that the preference in writing carries over to speech (since I'm not aware of any objective basis for making that claim). But if you are writing something and the phrase "shook their head/heads in disbelief"comes up, you may be interested to know that the preponderance of usage is unmistakably on the side of the plural *heads*.

---

The preference for "their husbands" over "their husband" in a Google Books search for the period 1700–2008 likewise shows a clear preference (in writing) for the plural form. Here is the relevant Ngram chart matching "their husbands" (blue line) against "their husband" (red line):

[image]

The support isn't unanimous, but it is pretty strong. Going forward, I would expect the split for "their spouses" versus "their spouse" to be less clear-cut because the modern use of *they* as a gender-neutral singular pronoun is likely to yield occurrences involving "a married person" and "their spouse"—a situation where TimLymington's test question "Did *they* have one spouse between them?" would be answered in the affirmative.

Comment: Thank you sooo much for taking care and doing the Ngram search. Their heads vs their head - I only asked as in some religions their deities have multiple heads. Shook their heads is just fine with me. Similarly "their husbands/wives" vs "their husband/wife" has a sociological background in that some societies permit the former. I love Ngrams and went and did "to whom" vs "to who". Whom in terminal decline?

Answer (score 0):

"Shake my heads" is surprisingly common, but "shake my head" is both much more common, and more logical, and all in all, the correct.

The more open case is "shake our head(s)". To use the plural works, because "we" presumably have more than one head between us, and hence we can "shake our heads", but the singular also works because "we" presumably have only one head each, and hence we can each "shake our head". The plural would be the more normal but the singular could still be argued for.

But for "my" you should definitely use "head".

Comment: >Shake my head*S*<? That is a tyop. At the end you come back to >for "my" you should definitely use "head"<. OK, but how does the question arise about more than one head per person?!!

Answer (score -1):

They shook their heads in disbelief - is fine. 
- heads shook in disbelief -  works too-
There may be a wide margin between what works and what works best.