# "They invited their friend(s)": What does it mean to use a singular or plural noun in this context?

Tags: grammatical-number

"They invited their friend(s)"

How to distinguish four situations:

1. They invited only one person, who is the common friend of all of them.
2. They invited one friend for each of them.
3. They invited one or more friend for each of them.
4. They invited more than one friend for each of them.

Comment: Related: [“They're using a cell phone” vs. “They're using cell phones”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/301625), [“They shook their heads” or “They shook their head”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/212139), [“On their back” or “on their backs”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/15322)

Comment: While yours wasn’t an unreasonable Question, it is unanswerable as it stands.

“They invited only one person, who is the common friend of all of them” should at worst be “They invited one (person), the (common) friend of all.”

“They invited one friend for each of them” should be “They invited one friend each”.

“They invited one or more friend for each of them” should be “They invited one or more friends each” or “They each invited…”

“They invited more than one friend for each of them” should be “They invited more than one friend each” or “They each invited…”

Comment: The trick is this: Each of them invited a friend. Forget they.

Answer (score 1):

I think people have been misinterpreting the question.

I believe the poster wants to know how to rephrase "They invited their friend(s)" to have each of those four meanings.

Here's how I'd do it:

1. They invited their friend.
2. They each invited a friend.
3. (Can't think of a way to concisely say one or more)
4. They each invited some friends.

Answer (score 0):

> They invited only one person, who is the common friend of all of them.

This means that a common or mutual friend of them all has been invited.

> They invited one friend for each of them.

This may be rephrased to "Each one of them invited a friend."

> They invited one or more friend for each of them.

Each of them invited one friend or more. Similarly, this may be rephrased to "Each one of them invited one or more friends."

> They invited more than one friend for each of them.

This may be rephrased to "Each one of them invited more than one friend."

Comment: If 'friends' is plural and no more specific information is given, I would understand it to mean (3).

Comment: Whereas *friend(s)* calls out that one of them only invited a single friend ...