# Wear a glove on participants' right hand or hands?

Tags: grammatical-number

I am writing a methods section of a research paper.

"Participants wore the glove on their right hand."

Here I'm confused whether I should say hand or hands, because 1) no one has two right hands, but 2) the total number of right hands = the number of participants > 1.

What do you think?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/212139/they-shook-their-heads-or-they-shook-their-head https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/12750/our-bodies-or-our-bodys and several other questions. But either is OK.

Comment: "**Each of the** participants wore the glove on their right hand."

Comment: Perhaps the most thorough treatment of the distributive singular and the distributive plural, including looking at cases where both are available or one is to be preferred, is at [Everybody's using a cell phone nowadays vs Everybody's using cell phones nowadays](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/301625/everybodys-using-a-cell-phone-vs-everybodys-using-cell-phones/548452#548452).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sentence is going to make more sense changed slightly.

'Every participant wore a glove on his/her (PC) or their -if one prefers - hand'.

Or 'each participant wore a glove on the right hand'.

Or 'the right hand of each participant sported (was covered by) a glove'.

Sometimes (often?) it's easier to change the sentence to accommodate the picture than it is to try to follow some 'rule', which may/not be apposite anyway.